# tinymce: configure toolbar programmatically?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

In a page with multiple instances of `tinymce`, is it possible to add logic to the parameters in the `object` passed to the `init` function?  I can do this if I write a function and call it twice, once for each `textarea` instance, but I wonder if it's available in the api.

Below, my selector finds two `textarea` instances, and I'd like them each to have different toolbars.  I thought something like `activeEditor.settings.toolbar` could access and change it, but it's not working.  Can `toolbar` be configured on init?

```
tinymce.init({
     selector: 'textarea',
     plugins:'link image imagetools',  
     toolbar: 'undo redo | cut copy paste',                
     setup:function(ed){
          ed.on("init",function(e){
               if(e.target.id == "conclude"){
                    // NOT WORKING: alter the toolbar:
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.toolbar = "undo redo";
               }                        
          });
     }
});
```

**EDIT:**
This isn't working either:

```
ed.on("BeforeRenderUI", function(e){
     e.target.settings.toolbar = "cut copy";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I built two distinct objects, each with their own set of parameters, to pass to multiple `tinymce.init` method calls.  I couldn't find a way to dynamically change the `toolbar` parameter from within the `object` being passed.

Answer (score 1):

There are some parameters that get used only on initialization and changing them won't do anything. You may try to do something like this (i am not sure this will work but it might):

```
 setup:function(ed){
      ed.on("beforeinit", function(e){
           if(e.target.id == "conclude"){
                ed.settings.toolbar = "undo redo";
           }                        
      });
 }
```

or

```
 setup:function(ed){
       if(ed.id == "conclude"){
            ed.settings.toolbar = "undo redo";
       }                        
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, Thariama.  Those seem like great ideas, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: i changed the second option - any change?

Comment: you could try the events 'BeforeRenderUI' and 'PreInit'

Comment: Those events seem like they'd do it, but I can't get it working.  I also tried adding the following in each of your suggested events, also with no luck:
var g = new tinyMCE.ui.Toolbar();
g.items = "cut copy";
tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.toolbar = g;

Comment: too bad, but maybe you could modify your selector from 'textarea' to 'textarea#your_textarea_id' in case you have a fixed id. this way you could switch the init parameter toolbar.

Comment: It appears that that's what I have to do. Thanks, Thariama, for following up.